# Way to use maxgap in na.locf for xts timeseries in R?

Tags: r, time-series, xts

`na.locf(xts_ts, maxgap=240)` doesn't seem to respect `maxgap` for `xts` timeseries. I think that for `xts` timeseries `na.locf.xts` is invoked (which doesn't document `maxgap`), and not `na.locf` which is from `zoo`.

Am I doing something wrong?

Should I convert the `xts` ts to a `zoo` ts, then call `na.locf` with `maxgap` and the convert back to `xts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxgap` is included in `na.locf.xts` on R-forge as of revision 553.  Use `install.packages("xts", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org")` to get the latest revision from R-forge.